# how to symetrize a part of the mesh in its normal orientation/position in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, bmesh

how can i symmetrize this mesh in this position? i mean to do it by the median point and by the normal orientation rather than local or global transforms orientation, in this case in the X axis in normal orientacion or custom orientation in this case. because i need to symmetrize in that position the selected mesh of the object, but i have notice that symmetrize option in b3d only works by the object´s median point and global axis, no i cant perform this in this exact position and orientation, so does someone know some trick to preform this action in edit mode?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

1. Establish your Pivot (transform origin, somewhere in the mirror plane). This probably involves <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> snapping the 3D Cursor to a known point, or the median of some selection, and setting the 'Pivot' to 'Cursor'.
2. Establish your Transform Orientation, either using the View, or more likely a Custom Orientation (the '+' at the right of the Transform Orientation dropdown). For example, it could be the normal of a face: select the face, and create an orientation from it. Z in that orientation will now be the direction of the face's normal.
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate your part..
4. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> scale the duplicate by -1 in the appropriate axis of your custom orientation, about your pivot.

You may have to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, turn the mirrored duplicate right-side-out.

Comment: shift+n does not do anything in b3d 2.81?

Comment: yeah it worked the another else thing you said but still its a bit inacurate and not a quick way to do it, there should be a free addon for this already...